Is there tutorial for forecasting binary otcomes from textual data using random forest with economic application?
I am looking for some tutorials on how to forecast some binary outcomes (e.g. change in interest rate vs no change), from textual data (e.g. speeches of central bank governors) using random forest. I am also looking preferably something that is applied to textual data that contain economic jargon, but I can accept also answers that provide more general tutorials.
If there is no tutorial is there perhaps a good paper, that goes step by step over their methodology?
